# Scrapy Recusrive (CrawlSpider) not crawling all links as expected

Tags: python, scrapy

So my issue is that I have this CrawlSpider

```
name = 'recursiveSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['industrialnetworking.com']
    
    custom_settings = {
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS' : 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
    }
    start_urls = [        
        'https://www.industrialnetworking.com/Manufacturers/Hirschmann'
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='div.catCell a::attr(href)'), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"/Manufacturers/Hirschmann*"), callback='parse_new_item')
    )
```

I am trying to hit the product pages of all "Hirshmann" products. I understand that my error is within the 2nd line of the "rules" where I have it allowing anything with Hirschmann*. Although I am unsure how to add a response.css/response.xpath as an argument for allow.

Ideally I would like it so that if the crawler all "div.catCell a:attr(href)" and recursive through them until it detects "response.css('td.cellDesc h2 a::attr(href)')", then it will send that link to my "parse_new_item". If that item is not found then continue with following all links that have "div.catCell a:attr(href)".

```
Example URL travel path ->
StartURL: https://www.industrialnetworking.com/Manufacturers/Hirschmann
Category: https://www.industrialnetworking.com/Manufacturers/Hirschmann-Rail-Switches
SubCategory: https://www.industrialnetworking.com/Manufacturers/Hirschmann-Switches-Unmanaged
Series: https://www.industrialnetworking.com/Manufacturers/Hirschmann-SPIDER-Family-Rail-Switches
END GOAL ->
Product: https://www.industrialnetworking.com/Manufacturers/Hirschmann-SPIDER-III-Rail-Switches/Hirschmann-SSL20-5TX-Rail-Switch-942-132-001
```

EDIT - Reason I am targeting the xpath/css path is because the links do not have any obvious pattern that I can use to target the urls.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally am not a big fan of the `crawlspider`. There are some cases when it is convenient, but I think in your situation sticking to crawling the links manually might be an easier approach.

Since you have multiple pages with the same format what you could do is feed each of the links back into the main `parse` method, until it finds the links that match the `td/h2/a` links, at which point it can then assign a different callback to parse the final product page using your `parse_new_item` method.

For example:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'recursiveSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['industrialnetworking.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.industrialnetworking.com/Manufacturers/Hirschmann']

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath("//div[@class='catCell']/a/@href").getall():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse)
        for url in response.xpath("//td[@class='cellDesc']/h2/a/@href").getall():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse_new_item)

    def parse_new_item(self, response):
        print(response)
        item_name = response.xpath("//div[@id='itmNam']/h1/text()").get()
        item = {"name": item_name}
        yield item
```

The output is really long so I just put the final tally below.

**OUTPUT**

```
<200 https://www.industrialnetworking.com/Manufacturers/Hirschmann-Greyhound-Switch-Power-Accessories/Hirschmann-Greyhound-1040-Industrial-Power-Supply-GPS1-KSY9HH>
2022-09-14 13:32:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.industrialnetworking.com/Manufacturers/Hirschmann-Greyhound-Switch-Power-Accessories/Hirschmann-Greyhound-1040-Industrial-Power-Supply-GPS1-KSY9H
H>
{'name': 'GPS1-KSY9HH Power Supply'}
2022-09-14 13:32:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-09-14 13:32:12 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 380892,
 'downloader/request_count': 483,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 483,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 9139340,
 'downloader/response_count': 483,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 471,
 'downloader/response_status_count/429': 12,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 22.988552,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 20, 32, 12, 287889),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 41356802,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 471,
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 4,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/429': 4,
 'item_scraped_count': 401,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 889,
 'log_count/ERROR': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 14,
 'request_depth_max': 5,
 'response_received_count': 475,
 'retry/count': 8,
 'retry/max_reached': 4,
 'retry/reason_count/429 Unknown Status': 8,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 483,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 483,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 483,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 483,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 14, 20, 31, 49, 299337)}
2022-09-14 13:32:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Hey Alexander, I'm having a new trouble, I ran your code last week and it was working perfectly, but I tried doing it this morning and I'm not able to hit anything, I'm not sure if it has something to do with my settings. I copied your code onto a new project and it still wasn't running as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your above mentioned webpage contains 14 listing urls.So you can use either xpath or css selectors only and you have to use `follow = False` to get rid of unnessary urls

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test'
   
    allowed_domains = ['industrialnetworking.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.industrialnetworking.com/Manufacturers/Hirschmann']
    


    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/Manufacturers/Hirschmann-'), follow = True, callback = 'parse_item'),
        )
    
    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'Title': response.xpath('//*[@id="itmNam"]/h1/text()').get()
            }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process =CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(TestSpider)
    process.start()
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I understand that there are 14 links within the start page. Your reply seems to help with part of the recursive issue. 
My question is - how would my crawler detect the response.css that I am trying to find to pass to the parse while still going through the rest of the links on a page?

Comment: See the above update whether it meets expectation or not.You can use only the first Rule. you can test it as I  didn't

Comment: I ran your updated code, and while I understand that usually one would allow via a url pattern, the problem with this specific site is that they have the following urls -
Series: https://www.industrialnetworking.com/Manufacturers/Hirschmann-SPIDER-Family-Rail-Switches
Product: https://www.industrialnetworking.com/Manufacturers/Hirschmann-SPIDER-III-Rail-Switches/Hirschmann-SSL20-5TX-Rail-Switch-942-132-001
Thus I am unable to use the url pattern as there is no set pattern on this site... I'll update my code to reflect the issue appropriately with this updated info.

Comment: I have updated my question with an example of the expected path travel for a single product from the start url. You will notice that this site has Hirschmann- in the path throughout all of them, so there is no unique pattern that I can target.